# How to read multiline data of a single field in a single line using Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get the data using select query in Powershell:-

Get-Team |  select $*.DisplayName, $*.Description

The data is coming in below format:-

DisplayName                       : MSTeam2

Description                       : Team created through PSScript

```
           add description by hitting enter
                                
           and new line but changed any privacy
```

The description is coming in multiline due to "Enter key hit" while writing the description by user.
I want to read it in a single line like this:-

DisplayName : MSTeam2

Description : Team created through PSScript add description by hitting enter and new line but changed any privacy

I have tried Replace() and -join but it isn't working.
Please help with this.

Comment: is the `$Description` value a multiline string? if so, you can split it on the newlines and then merge the resulting lines into one with `-join`.

Comment: welcome to SO. Please, take your time to properly format your questions before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Split & Join or replace statement and it should work the same.

```
# Split & Join
$Team.Description.Split([System.Environment]::NewLine) -join ''

# Replace
$Team.Description.Replace([System.Environment]::NewLine, '')
```

You could also use a calculated property so your selected object contain the modified description statement. This would work with split & join and replace equally.

```
$Team = Get-Team | Select DisplayName, 
@{'Name' = 'Description' ; 'Expression' = { $_.Description.Split([System.Environment]::NewLine) -join '' } }
```

Here's a complete reproducible example.

```
Function Get-Team {
    return [PSCustomObject]@{
        DisplayName = 'MSTeam2'
        Description = @"
Team created through PSScript
add description by hitting enter
and ne  line but changed any privacy
"@
    }    
}


# Original statement
$Team = Get-Team | Select DisplayName, Description
$Team.Description

#Color of the gods
$Cog = @{ForegroundColor = [System.ConsoleColor]::Cyan }


# Split & Join
Write-Host "Using Split & Join" @Cog
$Team.Description.Split([System.Environment]::NewLine) -join ''

# Replace
Write-Host "Using replace" @Cog
$Team.Description.Replace([System.Environment]::NewLine, '')

#Calculated property (could use one of the two above)
$Team = Get-Team | Select DisplayName, 
@{'Name' = 'Description' ; 'Expression' = { $_.Description.Split([System.Environment]::NewLine) -join '' } }

Write-Host 'Calculated property:' @Cog
Write-Host $($Team.Description)
```

Comment: Thanks Sage. However I am still facing an issue while getting the DisplayName and Description  in a log file. I am using $Description = @{'Name' = 'Description' ; 'Expression' = { $_.Description.Split([System.Environment]::NewLine) -join '' } } and later on $outtemp= $DistplayName+"^^"+$Description'                   
$outtemp  |Out-File -encoding UTF8 $UserTeamsCountDetailsFileLog -Append

Comment: @Mayuri That looks like another question unrelated to your initial inquiry. You might want to look into converting your file to CSV or JSON before outputing it to a file using the relevant ConvertTo cmdlets.

Comment: thanks for the solution. I tried outputing DisplayName and Description in a .log file in which I am getting "System.Collections.Hashtable" entry instead of Description. However, when I tried running the code given in previous comment without outputting the data into a log file , I am getting Description in desired format in Powershell. Can you help me with this?

Comment: @Mayuri I can only recommend asking another question. Provide all the relevant details and ideally a minimum reproducible example. If the question is clear and details are there, I am confident you'll get an answer fast. I don't have enough details from your comment to answer you just like that.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. We have asked this question with details here :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65246114/how-to-get-single-line-data-in-log-file-from-multi-line-data-for-a-field-using.     Can you please check it?