# How to get single line data in .log file from multi line data for a field using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am generating log file from below query. For "Description" field, I have multi line data and trying to get it in single line.

Example "Description" : "Testing sample application

```
                     with different entries 
                     and functionalities."
```

Get-Team | foreach {​​​​

select
$DisplayName =$.*DisplayName,
$Description = @{​​​​'Name' = 'Description' ; 'Expression' = {​​​​ $*.Description.Split([System.Environment]::NewLine) -join '' }​​​​ }​​​​

$outtemp= $DistplayName+"^^"+$Description

$outtemp |Out-File -encoding UTF8 "D:\Sample.log" -Append
}

**Getting below output in log file **

Team1^^System.Collections.Hashtable

Team2^^System.Collections.Hashtable

**In a Sample.log file, getting "System.Collections.Hashtable" instead of Description value.**

Expecting below output in sample.log file :

Team1^^Testing sample application with different entries and functionalities

Could you please help me on this?

Comment: Please, check (what is `$.DisplayName`?) and reformat your code. Also reveal more details from your log file (to be able to define **what is a description**, you also need to understand **what is *not* a description).

Comment: See: [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are after? (normalize a string as browsers do):

```
"Testing sample application 


with different entries 
and functionalities." -replace '\s+', ' '
```

Result:

```
Testing sample application with different entries and functionalities.
```